# Как запустить скрипт без браузера?

Tags: скрипт, php

Здравствуйте! Не могу сообразить, как запустить скрипт, когда кончается обратный отсчет. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
    $count_down = intval($enddate) - time(); 
if($count_down <= 0 && $order_info['order_state']; != 30){

//Надо запустить эту ссылку, где "member_refund" это название другого файла. Делаю так, но работает только при запуске в браузере. Крон использовать нельзя, так как передаются $_GET
<script>
$( function() {
$.get( "index.php?act=member_refund&op=add_refund_all&order_id=<?php echo $order_info['order_id'];?>&end_time_cancel=1" );
 } );
</script> 
}
```

**Обновление**

Объясню подробно. Покупатель оплачивает заказ. К времени заказа прибавляется определенное время (допустим 5 минут) и с этого момента начинается отсчет времени. Если продавец не отправил заказ в этот промежуток времени, то запускается скрип и заказ отменяется. Ответ не нужен, просто нужно запустить эту ссылку с $_GET параметрами. Работа скрипта заносится в базу. Скрипт запускается только один раз, потом меняется статус заказа и скрипт не запускается.

Покажите, пожалуйста, пример, как использовать exec, я пробовал - не получилось.

Comment: Что вам мешает запустить крон с гет параметрами?

Comment: Ну раз GET - значит браузер используется. А раз надо без браузера, то может быть на страничке [exec](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php) использовать?

Запускаем команду в фоне с нужным параметром - и все готово.

Хотя если бы вы задачу описали, было бы ясно, что хотите. Вам, может, на страничке нужно отобразить результат выполнения команды? Тогда зачем таймер?

Разрешить выполнять операцию через некоторое время? Ну так первый запрос - запускаем таймер и на клиенте отображаем отсчет. Как отсчет закончился - второй запрос, и если время на сервере вышло - выполняем, что надо.

Answer (score 1):

Пример запуска скрипта, например, используя [exec](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php) и [argv](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.argv.php):

index.php:

```
$orderId = 4; //$_GET['orderId'];
$command = "php exec.php {$orderId} > /dev/null 2>&1 &";
exec($command);
echo "DONE";
```

exec.php:

```
if (count($argv) == 1) {
    exit("Not enough args");
}
$orderId = intval($argv[1]);
if (!$orderId) {
    exit("OrderId is wrong");
}
sleep(5);
$filename = 'test.out';
file_put_contents($filename, $orderId);
```

Практически то же самое можно сделать через какой-нибудь брокер сообщений, например [Activemq](http://activemq.apache.org/). Примеры использования можно посмотреть [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/stomp.examples.php).

Тогда если отправка в очередь была неудачной, можно будет сказать об этом пользователю. Слушателей (т.е. постоянно запущенные скрипты) можно будет разнести на несколько серверов (если будет много пользователей сайта).

Activemq предоставляет различные средства для мониторинга очереди сообщений (например, через web-интерфейс, можно получать статистику консольными средствами, если настроить как следует).

Вот только... Эти способы (если через sleep делать) для обратного отсчета требуют того, чтобы они были запущены. Соответственно, если будет 100 запросов, то будет висеть 100 скриптов. А оно вам надо?

Может быть, стоит просто сохранять в базе заказы с указанием времени заказа и запускать по крону скрипт каждую минуту, который удаляет необработанные за некоторое время заказы? Тогда некоторый заказ может существовать на 59 секунд дольше необходимого, но я не думаю, что это будет критично, ведь так?

Т.е. что-то типа:

```
DELETE FROM `t_orders` WHERE `f_create_stamp` <= UTC_TIMESTAMP() - interval 5 minute
```

Если же время будет критично, тогда можно будет в фоне постоянно крутить скрипт, который каждую секунду удаляет из базы устаревшие данные (после удаления делаем sleep(1), чтобы не забирать все ресурсы).

**P.S. exec и stomp привел только для того, чтобы показать, как можно вызвать другой скрипт из страницы.**

Answer (score 0):

Так, а вообще ваш способ реализации не самый лучший. Чтобы все не переписывать, можно сделать так:

```
$count_down = intval($enddate) - time(); 
if($count_down <= 0 && $order_info['order_state']; != 30)
  {
    file_get_contents('index.php?act=member_refund&op=add_refund_all&order_id='. $order_info['order_id'].'&end_time_cancel=1');
  }
```

Comment: Т.е. вы предлагаете клиенту ждать n-минут? Т.е. вы реально думаете, что клиент будет ждать, пока несколько минут будет грузиться страница?

Ведь строчка:

    $count_down = intval($enddate) - time(); 
    if($count_down <= 0 && $order_info['order_state']; != 30)

это на клиентской странице. И это реализовано как таймер, а значит будет работать, пока время не выйдет.

Если даже таймер сделать в вызываемом файле, и к нему обращаться через file_get_contents, то что будет, если у вас за эти 5 минут будет вызвано 1К скриптов? Эти 1К скриптов будут висеть в памяти? А оно надо?